# Static ArrayList always Replacing the older values

Tags: java, android, variables, methods, static

i have class in which i declare a static variable id

```
class id
{
  private static int id;
  public int getid()
 {
  return this.id
 }
public void setid(int id)
 {
    this.id=id;
 }
}
```

i have another class in which i create the object of this class and call these methods

```
class abc
{
    id obj=new id();
      int a=obj.getid();
    obj.setid(a+1);

}
```

now i am storing it to an static ArrayList in another class

```
class ser
{
  private static ArrayList<id>al=new ArrayList<id>();

  public static addid(id obj)
 {
   al.add(obj);
 }
}
```

now the problem is that it replaces the object every time i add the object to the list what is the error please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Static vs Instance Variables: Difference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21204589/static-vs-instance-variables-difference)

Comment: Yes please tell me how to do it with static variable declared....

Answer (score 0):

All the objects id have the same value for the variable id because it is a static member of the class. So when you add several instances of the class id to the list, all instances have the same value for id. Are you sure you want the variable id to be static?

Comment: Yes because i need to retain the value of id until or unless the program is running