# What is a member variable? Is it the same as an instance variable?

Tags: java, variables, member-variables

What is a **member variable**? Is a member variable and an instance variable the same thing?

An instance variable is a variable declared in a class and accessed throughout the code, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Static vs Instance Variables: Difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21204589/static-vs-instance-variables-difference)

Comment: A member variable and an instance variable are different terms for the same thing.

Answer (score 8):

The instance variables and class variables are generally called member variables.

See [Declaring Member Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html):

> There are several kinds of variables:
>
> - Member variables in a class—these are called fields.
> - Variables in a method or block of code—these are called local variables.
> - Variables in method declarations—these are called parameters.

And [Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html):

> The Java programming language defines the following kinds of
>   variables:
>
> - Instance Variables (Non-Static Fields) Technically speaking, objects
>     store their individual states in "non-static fields", that is, fields
>     declared without the static keyword. Non-static fields are also known
>     as instance variables because their values are unique to each instance
>     of a class (to each object, in other words); the currentSpeed of one
>     bicycle is independent from the currentSpeed of another.
> - Class Variables (Static Fields) A class variable is any field declared
>     with the static modifier; this tells the compiler that there is
>     exactly one copy of this variable in existence, regardless of how many
>     times the class has been instantiated. A field defining the number of
>     gears for a particular kind of bicycle could be marked as static since
>     conceptually the same number of gears will apply to all instances. The
>     code static int numGears = 6; would create such a static field.
>     Additionally, the keyword final could be added to indicate that the
>     number of gears will never change.
> - Local Variables Similar to how an object stores its state in fields, a
>     method will often store its temporary state in local variables. The
>     syntax for declaring a local variable is similar to declaring a field
>     (for example, int count = 0;). There is no special keyword designating
>     a variable as local; that determination comes entirely from the
>     location in which the variable is declared — which is between the
>     opening and closing braces of a method. As such, local variables are
>     only visible to the methods in which they are declared; they are not
>     accessible from the rest of the class.
> - Parameters You've already seen examples of parameters, both in the
>     Bicycle class and in the main method of the "Hello World!"
>     application. Recall that the signature for the main method is public
>     static void main(String[] args). Here, the args variable is the
>     parameter to this method. The important thing to remember is that
>     parameters are always classified as "variables" not "fields". This
>     applies to other parameter-accepting constructs as well (such as
>     constructors and exception handlers) that you'll learn about later in
>     the tutorial.

Answer (score 5):

There is no mention of "member variable" in [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/jls8.pdf).

"Instance variable" is defined in [§ 4.12.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.3):

> An *instance variable* is a field declared within a class declaration without using the keyword `static`.