# When do we use Class Variable, rather than using Object of class?

Tags: java, static-variables, class-variables

I am studying about static variables. They say that static variables are class variables. 
They gave an example like this

```java
class Bicycle{
    private static int noOfBicycles = 0;
}
```

When calling this we can directly use the name of the class to call this variable without creating any object, i.e.

```
Bicycle.noOfBicycles
```

So when do we need these static variables rather than instance variables?

Comment: whenever you required to rid out from repeated variable then we use static variable instead because static is referred to memory management.

Answer (score 0):

When a variable is declared as static,  a single copy of the variable is created and shared among all objects at a class level. Static variables are, essentially, global variables. All instances of the class share the same static variable.

Instance variables are non-static variables and are declared in a class outside any method, constructor or block. As instance variables are declared in a class, these variables are created when an object of the class is created and destroyed when the object is destroyed.

The main differences between static and non static variables are
[better explained here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-static-and-non-static-variables-in-java/#:%7E:text=Non%20static%20variables%20cannot%20be,memory%20used%20by%20a%20program.&text=Static%20variables%20are%20shared%20among,that%20instance%20of%20a%20class.)

Also already answered [Static vs Instance Variables: Difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21204589/static-vs-instance-variables-difference)