# Passing variable from another file and then use variable within to another method within same class

Tags: java, oop

I am trying to call a variable from another class in another to the second java file

```
public class selectFile {
    public void hdrFile(){
        String hdrName = "directory";
        readImage sendVari = new readImage();

        sendVari.setprintHDR(hdrName);
    }
}
```

```
public class readImage {
    private String hdr_dir;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        selectFile call_vari = new selectFile();
        call_vari.hdrFile();
    }

    public void setprintHDR(String hdr_dir){
        this.hdr_dir = hdr_dir;
    }

    public String getprintHDR(){
        return hdr_dir;
    }

    public void anotherMethod(){
        System.out.println(getprintHDR());
    }
}
```

I am doing this because I want to use "anotherMethod" Method in second in the third file, but when I am testing in the second java file by printing it to the terminal "anotherMethod" cannot print any hdr_dir even I return hdr_dir. But if I check "setprintHDR" by printing it to the command everything seem fine, it returns "directory"

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        readImage call_vari = new readImage();
        call_vari.anotherMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: but you are not calling anotherMethod() anywhere , right?

Comment: yes, I call it in another file too, but for now I am just testing it

Comment: in the code that you have shared, where is the anotherFile from where you are calling this method?

Comment: I just edit the question

Comment: are both files named as readImage?

Comment: of course no, I just fix :(

Comment: so your question is when you run the main class, hdr_dir comes as null, right ?

Comment: yes, it return nothing, the hdr_dir only come out in method getprintHDR, but not in other methods

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241509/discussion-between-gurkirat-singh-guliani-and-beam291).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to use the updated value in another object( basically trying to share the value between multiple objects), you should keep your variable hdr_dir as **static**. [Static vs Instance Variables: Difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21204589/static-vs-instance-variables-difference)

You were currently using the variable as instance one due to which if one object updates the value, it will remain specific to that object only.
For your main class,

```
public class Main {
    
//    private String hdr_dir;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int res = 0; 
         selectFile call_var = new selectFile();
         call_var.hdrFile();
        readImage call_vari = new readImage();
//        call_var.anotherMethod();
//        call_vari.setprintHDR("printHDR");
        call_vari.anotherMethod();
    }
}
```

and the output is

```
value of hdr_dir is passed is  -------directory // doing some console logging 
value of hdr_dir assigned is  -------directory
directory
```